# Tricks of griling kabab

Tags: meat, vegetables, grilling

I like to make kabobs, but when i try to turn over the kabob so it cooks evenly, the meat and vegetables sometimes spin around on the skewers.Is there a trick to grilling kabobs so i don't have to turn each piece of meat  with tongs??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a few suggestions on things to try:

- If you're using metal skewers you might like to consider switching to wood / bamboo instead. I've never been that keen on metal skewers for that very reason.
- I've noticed that sometimes I have a tendency to lift and rotate at the same time so I'm starting to turn while some of the food is still in contact with the grill and doesn't turn. Make sure you lift them well up and then turn gently in a separate motion.
- Although just about everyone says to soak wood / bamboo before using so it doesn't burn for things that are fairly quick to cook I often don't and that seems to help as well. You'll need to be careful it doesn't catch direct flames doing it that way though.
- For things like chicken that you want to cook thoroughly I normally leave the hood down for most of the cooking and getting some extra heat from all directions reduces the number of times you'll need to turn them.

Answer (score 2):

One technique that I use is to pack the meat and veg on the skewer pretty tightly, lengthwise. In my opinion, this has the benefit of making the food density more consistent for better, more even cooking, and reducing the spinning. Plus everything that PeterJ said.

Cutting all the ingredients about the same size helps with this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are laying them out on some kind of grill or griddle...
also assuming your skewers are round metal - otherwise invest in some flattened ones, like they use in Turkish restaurants.  Metal is better than wood at transmitting heat, so your food cooks quicker &  more evenly - & can be re-used.

Leave a space at one end when you lay them out on your grill, room for one more kebab...

When time to turn - drag/roll them one at a time into the space left by the last move. Everything will roll together.

If you didn't leave a space, then all you need to do is lift one out first, then juggle it back in at the other side afterwards.